# Streaming de vídeos com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express.js, streaming

Bom dia! Tenho uma API REST rodando em Node com Express, e o frontend rodando VueJS. A API me devolve uma lista com o nome de alguns vídeos que anteriormente foram armazenados em um storage, e um botao "Reproduzir". Ao clicar nesse botão, começa a busca pelo vídeo. O frontend invoca uma rota na API que deveria trazer o vídeo em partes(O usuário vai assistindo enquanto o navegador traz o restante do vídeo, igual ao Youtube). O problema é que o servidor me devolve todo o conteúdo do vídeo apenas uma vez só. Estou testando com um vídeo de 300MB e chega de uma vez só no frontend os 300MB. Acredito que deveria chegar aos poucos para eu ir incrementando.

Minha rota na API:

```
async getVideoStreaming (request, response) {

const {video} = request.params;

var ep = new AWS.Endpoint(URL_STORAGE);

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: USER_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY,
    endpoint: ep,
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01'
});

var params = {Bucket: 'test_projects', Key: video};
var s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream({highWaterMark: 1 * 1024}).pipe(response);

// Listen for errors returned by the service
s3Stream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
s3Stream.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Done.');
});


// Tentativa com arquivo do servidor, sem conectar com o storage:
// filename = './tmp/myvideo.mp4'
// var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {highWaterMark: 1 * 1024});
// readStream.pipe(response);

// fileStream.on('data', data => {
//  console.log('new data: ', data);
// })

},
```

Minha função no frontend:

```
api.get('project/videostreaming/' + videoName, headers)
.then(async response => {

console.dir(response);
console.log('Chegando dados');
console.log(response.data.length) // Isso toda apenas uma vez e imprime o tamanho total do 
vídeo ao invés de imprimir o tamanho parcial

// Como eu imagino que deveria ser:
// meuVideo = meuVideo + currentChunk

})
.catch(error => {
    errors.handler(error, 'Não foi possível reproduzir o vídeo.');              
})
```

Estou pesquisando e lendo muito sobre isso já fazem alguns dias mas não consigo resolver isso. Outro detalhe de frontend: Como o arquivo é grande e chega uma única vez, na hora de colocar no player, o front trava. Agradeço por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Também estou a trabalhar (nas horas vagas) num projeto [de streaming de audio](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/node-audio-server). Vou voltar mais logo aqui e tentar ajudar se ninguém tiver ajudado ainda.

Comment: Okay Sérgio, muito obrigado, ficarei na expectativa.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma, caso alguém passe pela mesma situação:

Adaptei a minha aplicação para carregar a URL da API que fornece o arquivo direto na tag   e . Na API a alteração foi a seguinte:

```
var s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream({highWaterMark: 1 * 1024}).pipe(response);
```